# Playing m3u8 using signed urls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, video-streaming, m3u8, pre-signed-url

I want to stream an `m3u8` file from Google Cloud Storage using signed URLs. I tried to generate a signed URL for the `manifest.m3u8` file; however, this didn't work since the different streams don't have a valid signed URL either.

I'm trying to come up with a solution to give a client access to all the needed segments when reading out the `manifest.m3u8`.

Is it possible to swap out the different streams in the `manifest.m3u8` file with signed URLs to each stream? Am I missing something?

**Manifest.m3u8**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="Test Language",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio-hls-fmp4.m3u8"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=774348,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=530950,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,AUDIO="audio",CODECS="hvc1.1.4.L123.90,mp4a.40.2"
video-hd-hls-fmp4.m3u8 <-- SWAP THIS WITH SIGNED URL
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=762873,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=507776,RESOLUTION=1280x720,AUDIO="audio",CODECS="hvc1.1.4.L123.90,mp4a.40.2"
video-sd-hls-fmp4.m3u8 <-- SWAP THIS WITH SIGNED URL
```

The only helpful resource I found online was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778840/google-cloud-storage-signed-url-for-media), however, this technique seemed fairly cumbersome to me. In the meantime, are there other methods to accomplish this since this post is from 8 years ago?

**PS:** I'm using [Google's NodeJS Cloud Storage library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage)

---

#### Objective

In essence, I'm searching for a solution to stream/serve `manifest.m3u8` without having to go through my own server. I'm trying to minimize the load on my server as much as possible. This can be done using signed URLs.

The [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/transcode-video#play_video) use signed URLs, however they set all the `m3u8` resources *publicly available* in order to successfully stream it. AWS uses something like signed cookies, which solves the problem. However GCP only has this feature available within `Cloud CDN`, not `Cloud Storage`.

What are some other methods to successfully stream an `m3u8` file?

Comment: One solution would be to parse the manifest replacing file references with Signed URLs **but** this assumes that the user will play *all* the streams before the Signed URLs expire. An optimization would be to only generate the Signed URL for a stream on-demand but it's unclear whether the clients would support this.

Comment: Because Signed URLs don't require credentials, they're often used as a solution where a user **is** still required to provide credentials these are just handled out-of-band. Once the user is auth'd, you generate a Signed URL and give it to the user. To avoid the limitations mentioned above, you may want to consider proxying your users' requests to GCS. The user provides some form of credentials to the proxy and when the user requests a stream from the manifest, the proxy receives the request, authenticates to GCS and provides the stream.

Comment: Given the first solution, would it be acceptable to set the signed URLs expiration on 30 days? Since the chance that someone would guess a signed URL is very small.

Comment: @DazWilkin wouldn't the _"parse the manifest replacing file references with Signed URLs"_ solution require me to create a separate `manifest.m3u8` file for each request made? Since every single manifest file needs to have unique signed URLs?

Comment: I don't understand how your solution is architected. I'm providing an *a priori* suggestion in response to your question. Presumably (!) you serve manifests to customers and, when you provide the manifest, you'd generate the Signed URLs. To be clear, from what I understand of your solution, I think Signed URLs is **not* a good solution.

Comment: 1) The max expiration time for V4 Signed URLs is 7 days. However, Signed URLs created by the SignBlob API should not be issued for longer than 12 hours due to key rotation. 2) The likelihood of someone guessing a Signed URL is very low, but you would be amazed how fast secrets spread on the dark web. Targets with value will be discovered and advertised.

Comment: @DazWilkin I'm kind of new to streaming m3u8 files. So as far as I understand, streaming m3u8 files via a signed URL is not done. What would be a better solution? Streaming directly from the server itself? For me (personally), the main objective is to keep as much load away from the server. That's why I chose signed URLs in the first place.

Comment: @Michiel I have exactly the same case, how did you solve it? What's the best approach to stream the videos from a private google bucket?

Comment: @AliBassam hey Ali, since then we've moved away from signed URLs. If I remember correctly I never figured out how to do it. The reason for moving away from signed URLs is because we need to be able to cache the content we send to our clients. Since a signed URL is always unique for every request (even if it's the same image) you won't be able to cache it in the browser, because the browser uses the URL to identify whether it's cached or not. Does that make sense? There are definitely ways to handle caching with signed URLs, it includes some hacky stuff that would only make things more complex.